# Is there an equivalent to Latex's \endinput in Python-Sphinx

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx

LateX and Python-Sphinx are word-processors, transforming formatted content towards a target document. The usual workflow when working with large documents is to split them in smaller files (sections, chapters) and use a specific file as a table of contents (`main.tex` in most Latex projects, `index.rst` in Sphinx).

In Latex, it is possible to stop the processing of a specific file by using a `\endinput` command (then, the processor will move on to the next section or chapter).

I cannot find such a directive in Python-Sphinx's documentation. Does it exists? If not, is there a way to implement this behavior?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#options-for-latex-output and http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/latex.html#module-latex

Comment: My question was probably not clear enough: I am looking for a way to stop sphinx from including "the end of a file" for **any** output format (the first being html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I know of. But you can do the inverse by including what you want, which would have the same effect as excluding what you don't want, by using the [`ifconfig`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/ifconfig.html) Sphinx extension.  You might have to indent what you want.

Comment: I already use this directive for other purposes, I didn't think of using it this way, thank you very much! It is indeed the best way to achieve what I need.